# Why isn't it easy to put an ampere-meter into any battery driven electronics?

Tags: battery-charging, multimeter, cellphone, laptop

I can buy a cheap multimeter which has an ampere-meter function. Great.

Battery driven computer equipment like laptops and cellphones are complex, and for power / battery management I suppose an ampere-meter would be great.  I should be able to tell the exact mAh of a charge cycle, and of the discharge cycle, all just by integrating the current measurement over time. Along with the voltage on the batteries that should tell me pretty instantly (over one full charge-discharge cycle) what my actual battery capacity is.

It seems this is not how these devices work. For example, the iPhone 11 has a "calibrations" that takes days and weeks to complete to find out what the health of the battery is.

Here I am asking about principles.  How come the ampere-meter is so cheap and yet it is not integrated so easily into this equipment? I am not talking about cheap equipment, so what is the practicality and electrical engineering reason that it is not as simple as I think it should be?

---

BTW, I found on said iPhone [a treasure trove of low level battery related measurements](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458960/how-to-interpret-the-very-rich-iphone-analytics-data-about-battery-use-health). Having trouble interpreting them yet, clearly this seems to say that these electronics equipment do have such data, it's just not necessarily accessible on the UI.

Comment: Please let us establish first : how you conclude that, "But it seems this is not how these devices work."  I don't know of devices that take days and weeks to calibrate.  Please help us to help you.

Comment: Integrating the current over time is not so easy. If the current is small, a small offset error will accumulate a large error over time. The current consumption of laptop or cellphone changes very much from sleep state to high workload. The integration should not only be calculated for some minutes only but also for several days without loosing precision.

Comment: @Marla I added the example of the iPhone 11.

Answer (score 6):

The fundamental confusion that prompted the - quite valid! - question is between what is colloquially meant by "charge" vs. what the engineers and physicists call charge.

The colloquial "charge" is something between 0% and 100%. The physical charge unit is a Coulomb.

The "charge meter" is not being calibrated. It measures charge fairly accurately in Coulombs. Can you make any use of Coulombs if they were displayed instead of the 0%-100% "charge remaining"? Do you even know how many Coulombs your battery stores? Or, if you were to measure usable energy instead of charge: perhaps an energy meter in Joules (Watt-seconds) would help you more?

What is calibrated is the **battery**, not the charge integrator, even though the latter may incidentally be have long term drift that is calibrated as well, as a bonus. The battery is not a constant: it is a complex electrochemical device and its capacity changes over time and temperature. Specifically, the charge needed to go from fully charged state to fully discharged state, is what's being calibrated. Again: it's not the "charge meter", but the amount of charge that "fits" into the battery, that's measured.

> I should be able to tell the exact mAh of a charge cycle, and of the discharge cycle

How is that helpful? If that was shown on the display of the phone, would you be able to make any use of it? How would you know how much charge is actually available? All you'd know is the integral on electricity meter, so to speak. Not very useful at all in judging how much device life you got left. I know how many "% of battery" are used up by listening to YouTube videos for an hour with the phone in my pocket, running at minimum brightness. I would be unhappy if you asked me to remember two mAh values and subtract between them, or to have to remember to zero out the mAh meter like you would an odometer when the phone is just about dead. And then remember to read the mAh meter at full battery before I start using the phone after fully charging it. And also to slowly rescale my idea of "full battery" over multiple partial charge-discharge cycles. That's what the battery charge calibration does.

There are progressively better mathematical battery models that help with charge estimation without needing a full charge-discharge cycle. In spite of those models being quite usable, they still drift with time, because ultimately they aren't oracles and can't divine what's going on inside the battery. They can only estimate it, based on instantaneous current, cell voltage, temperature, and battery history. The most advanced of those models are proprietary and a trade secret. I haven't had to recalibrate my phone's charge meter in a long time I think, and it's quite accurate in practice.

> iPhone 11 has a "calibrations" that takes days and weeks to complete to find out what the health of the battery is

That's because health of the battery is way more than just how much usable charge you can stuff into it. Battery health is determined by doing essentially a system identification on the battery plant. There's a mathematical model of the battery, with several parameters and state variables, and those are estimated over some time. Once the model converges to observed battery behavior over a range of conditions (charge state, load current, temperature, and some battery history parameters), the health is calculated based on parameters of the model.

This battery health estimation is **way more complex** than just measuring charge in mAh - a rather trivial endeavor that nobody has any trouble with.

Comment: The normal iPhone user would probably not know what to make of 3,110 mAh, (which, with 1 A = 1 C/s is 3.11 C/s*3600s = 11,196 C). An expert mode that would tell me how many coulomb went into the battery during the charge cycle would be lovely for me. And I could tell that if 3000 was put in then it's 96.5% of the total nominal capacity.

Comment: @GuntherSchadow get an Android phone and it's easy to download an app that will tell you that kind of thing. If similar apps aren't available for iPhone... well, you can guess why.

Comment: @GuntherSchadow Any laptop will typically give you that sort of data easily (because the OS gives applications much more low-level access to the HW, unlike heavily sandboxed phone OSes). You will typically get three numbers in coulombs: rated nameplate capacity,current total capacity (which decreases as the battery ages),and current state of charge. That's what the OS needs to give you an estimate of remaining runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty common that an older battery "dies" when its internal resistance causes the supply voltage to drop below what the regulator can handle, even though its 50 or 60% charged (as measured by current).  Just measuring current (which many devices do) won't capture that since most of the current supplied to the battery is still in the cell.  Hence calibration is more than just mA supplied.

Comment: We measure normally only the current and this is the value we use to describe the loading state. The problem is the changing in capacity during time. If the electrodes are get damaged because the cell is used in the maximum voltage range, then the capacity is decreasing. You only know the new capacity if you have done a complete discharge and charge cycle. --- An other thing is the parallel resistance (lithium dendrites make holes in the membrane because of high loading current) inside of the battery and the growing self discharge because of this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem:

1. You can no measure the capacity (normally only the current in mAh) of a battery extreme exactly, because of this you will have difference between the measured ant the real capacity value. So you need some more information about the condition of the charging, like the voltage limits.
2. You do not want to waste energy while the phone is in standby or sleep-mode, so you normally do not measure the whole time and at the end, the effort would not pay back. You know the minimum and maximum voltage and this are the limits we pay attention.

How it is done:

- If we have a LiIon-cell, then we know the voltage range were it should be full or empty. My smartphone has a 4.35V cell and this is the charging-end-voltage. You load the cell up with a current and a maximum of 4.35V, this means at the end the current is decreasing till 1/10C is reached and then the charging will be disabled.
- To know the capacity of the smartphone you can discharge it till 3.6V (under this voltage the resistance of the cell is rising very fast, but you can discharge the cell till 3.0V or till 2.5V) and then you can load up it again till it reached 4.35 Volt. The internal current measurement counts the current per time value. But this should not take days or weeks. There must be something wrong if it takes so long or Apple is doing something useless to convince the customer to buy a new phone very soon.

If you follow this advice, then you make two charge cycles and then the device knows the correct capacity. >[Link](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/calibrate-iphone-battery/)< This takes a while, but not days.